# How to change circle color using annotation plugin

Tags: java, android, mapbox

Using MapBox Android SDK (7.0.0) and Annotations Plugin (0.4.0) I am trying to change the color of a circle when it is clicked. The listener is being called, but the color does not change. What am I missing? Thanks

```
circleManager.addClickListener(new OnCircleClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnnotationClick(Circle circle) {
        circle.setCircleColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.myColor, null));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

I figured it out. You need

```
circleManager.update(circle);
```

afterwards to update the annotation